# Nested Interface

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I try to understand nested interfaces in Angular 5/TS and I can't reach any correct point. I created two interfaces:

```
export  interface Person {
    person: PersonData;
}

export interface PersonData {
    id: number;
    speed: number;
    weigth: number;

}
```

Also I mock a JSON server: https://www.jasonbase.com/things/VmaZ.json (see below).

```
{
  "person": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "speed": 100,
      "weigth": 20
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "speed": 70,
      "weigth": 20
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "speed": 10,
      "weigth": 30
    }
  ]
}
```

And the questions is:

- Is my thinking way is correct?
- How to read this Data by Observable Service and read and write to object like test.person.speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify using only one interface, a good sample is:

```
export  interface Person {
    id: number;
    speed: number;
    weigth: number;
}
```

And in your component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Person } from './person'; // get interface
import data from './person.mock.json'; // get mock

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  people: Person[] = data.person;
}
```

And loop like:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let person of people">
   id {{person.id}} | speed {{person.speed}}  | weight {{person.weigth}} 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Working example: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rd3sqp)

Answer (score 2):

You dont need another interface just to hold the reference of `PersonData`

`Person` interface seems unnecessary, because you can simply create array of references pointing to `PersonData` interface.

`let personData : PersonData[]`

And then access them like `personData[i].id` or `personData[i].speed`

Comment: Ok but we should think wider. What if my JSON will grow and I will add new array?

Comment: Do you mean the properties inside `PersonData` will increase or the items inside JSON array will increase?